# Laravel 9 - Error Class BooksSeeder does not exist

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-9, laravel-api

When i run **php artisan make:seeder --class=BooksSeeder** I am getting the following error:

```
The "--class" option does not exist.
```

Can anyone help me out?
I'm still new to Laravel

My **DatabaseSeeder Class**:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();
    }
}
```

My **BooksSeeder Class**:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Books;


class BooksSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            Books::create([
                'name' => $faker->sentence,
                'author' => $faker->name,
                'publish_date' => $faker->date,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously `make:seeder` command just doesn't takes `--class` param. you can use `php artisan make:seeder --help` to see command info. and take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/seeding#writing-seeders)

p.s. why do you even try to generate seeder if you already have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax.

To create seeder, use:

```bash
php artisan make:seeder BooksSeeder
```

To run seeder, use:

```bash
php artisan db:seed --class=BooksSeeder
```